# How do I prevent an end user from modifying an object by its primary key via an overposting attack in C#/.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm sure this is an obvious answer, but I am learning C# and .NET for the first time now. In Microsoft's [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-5.0) for ASP.NET Core MVC, the example shows including an object's ID property in the Edit bind.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id, [Bind("ID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price")] Movie movie)
{
    if (id != movie.ID)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    // other stuff
}
```

In the view, there is also a hidden input field for the ID; I understand why this is necessary. Anyway, I followed along and verified that by finding that hidden field in my browser's HTML viewer and changing the value of the ID in that hidden field to another known valid ID, I could effectively submit changes that would be applied to an object other than the one I had initially clicked on to edit.

Is this just a mistake on Microsoft's part for including ID in the bind in their example, or am I missing something? This seems very dangerous on a production site. When I removed ID from the bind include I get a 404 when trying to submit my changes, so it's obviously not as simple as that. I assume this is because the `if (id != movie.ID)` check fails but I am not completely sure.

What is the solution here to allow the site to function properly (i.e. send the target ID to the controller and then to the database) without allowing a bad actor to supply their own ID?

Comment: Typical poor coding practice from Microsoft tutorials. I use them as an indication of how an object might be used, not as the definitive "this is correct code". Obviously one uses a token to identify the user, then limit which objects they can modify based on that

Comment: But how does one limit that? I tried removing ID from the bind as I said, but that gave me a 404.

Comment: You need to pass through an extra session token parameter or cookie, which identifies the user, you then verify that against the allowed users on that object (`Movie` in this case, except there is no list of permissions here, which is why this example is bad)

Comment: This issue doesn't depend the end user's identity or permissions (I haven't put in authentication of any kind yet). The issue is that the end user can click on an object to edit in the web app, then open the browser's HTML viewer, find the hidden ID field corresponding to that object, then change the value to a valid ID of another object in the database. When the end user saves the changes, the form passes that new ID, thereby modifying that other object instead of the one actually clicked on.

Comment: If you have no intention of implementing identity checking or permissions then you're happy to allow any user to edit those resources, right? So why do you mind if they change the hidden ID field in the HTML? Sure, it's a creepy thing for them to do, but they're permitted to do it, so why do you mind? If it was dangerous you'd implement authorization and authentication, wouldn't you? So I think @Charlieface is right. If you want to protect yourself from this attach, you assume that you'll implement authentication and authorization before you put this live.

Comment: Well yeah, if you don't know who's on the other end of the wire, why would you let them do anything at all, including editing what they clicked on? Anything client-side is eminently forge-able. I suppose you could supply a token with the view, which gets supplied back on edit, then at least in theory it's the same person who originally made the view request is the one editing. But you know nothing about who is connecting in the first place. Authetication is key

Comment: I mean I'm just starting to learn this stuff... I even said I haven't done authentication *yet*. I plan to in the future. But the issue I am describing still would not be fixed with authentication. Authentication would tell me who messed with things, but would not prevent them from doing so.

Comment: This vulnerability is called an [insecure direct object reference](https://owasp.org/www-project-web-security-testing-guide/latest/4-Web_Application_Security_Testing/05-Authorization_Testing/04-Testing_for_Insecure_Direct_Object_References).

Comment: `the issue I am describing still would not be fixed with authentication`...no but it could potentially be fixed with authorisation (which is where you use an authenticated user's identity to decide what actions they are allowed to take / which data items they are allowed to interact with). So if you received a request containing the ID of a user, and your authorization data tells you that user should not have access to modify that ID, then you'd know the request was tampered with and could refuse to process it

Comment: Please realise that `I could effectively submit changes that would be applied to an object other than the one I had initially clicked on to edit` isn't actually a problem at all **unless** it results in a request that the person should not be permitted to perform. Otherwise, it's just as if they had clicked on that other item to edit it to begin with. It's odd, but there's no actual harm done. A browser is only a way to guide the user into sending correct and useful HTTP requests to the server. It cannot ultimately control what they decide to send...and

Comment: ... other software can also make can also make HTTP requests to your server. That may, or may not, be perceived as a threat, depending on the nature of the application. P.s. I wouldn't really describe what you've talked about as an "over-posting" attack - that's when the model binder / validator permits the client to populate more fields in the object than were originally intended on the form - e.g. if a user can edit someone's name but not their role, something like that. Just changing the ID is altering the post, but not over-posting extra fields.

Comment: P.s. typo above, I said `So if you received a request containing the ID of a user`...I meant the ID of a movie to edit, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I mean I'm just starting to learn this stuff... I even said I haven't done authentication yet. I plan to in the future. But the issue I am describing still would not be fixed with authentication. Authentication would tell me who messed with things, but would not prevent them from doing so.

You can't solve it without authentication **and authorization**, neither you should try to hard. In the end, from application perspective you will never know, which entity (with what ID) was supposed to be changed.

Only thing you can check is, if the user is permitted to change it, based on your business rules for that function, for example

- Check if user has a specific permission to edit/update that type of entities (i.e. `ManageUsers` policy). Such a policy already implies, the user is allowed to manage all users, so if he decides to change the ID, well so he do. He could done the same by selecting a different user end editing it. From the point of the application nothing changed
- If the user is only allowed to edit users, belonging to a specific group, well then you need to add means to determine that, i.e. add some permissions that indicate the user is allowed to edit groups, but only specific ones (i.e. where the user has an administrator role).

  In that case, you need to load the entity (`var user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id)`, then check the group to what that user belongs (`var groups = soemService.GetUserGroups(user)`) and then check if the logged in user, has the permissions to modify this groups (`bool hasAccess = authorizationService.CanEditRoles(groups, this.User)` (where `this.User` is the logged in user from the controller's property) and if successful, then allow the change, otherwise reject it via `return Forbidden()` result)

There may be other logics you can apply, but it depends on your application, i.e. you may only want users to edit their own entities, in that case the entity needs to have a `AuthorId` property, which you check against the logged in users Id (`if(user.AuthorId == loggedInUserId) { ... }`).

In anyways, all this logic only works, when you have authentication. Without it, all kind of checks are pointless, because you have no means to find out what a specific user is allowed to or not.